# Data normalization (reward/penalization) in a learning paradigm

Tags: bayesian, normalization, adjustment

wondering if folks can offer guidance on this data normalization problem. When trying to determine retention of information after a time delay, the retention rate needs to be adjusted for # of items that were learned initially (otherwise 10/10 and 5/5 would both be 100% retention). Someone proposed to me a solution based on Bayes theorem, which seems to work. However, during learning some items were learned quickly and kept getting recalled over multiple trials (overlearning), whereas other items may have only been recalled at the tail end of the learning trials, so I'd like to weight the less-learned items that have lower probabilities of being retained (and also penalize the more-learned items if they are not retained). Is there a principled way of accomplishing this? Thanks!